# Ivy Lane Denizen similar effects

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I feel like I have seen it before but I can't find it, I'm looking for a creature that is pretty similar to [Ivy Lane Denizen](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIvy%20Lane%20Denizen%5d) but in a different color. I know about [Cathars' Crusade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCathars%27%5d%2b%5bCrusade%5d) but this is for a [Marchesa, the Black Rose](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMarchesa%2c%20the%20Black%20Rose%5d) deck so green and white won't work (just my luck). If anyone know about a card that is similar to or to the same effect as these cards that would be awesome. Also the counter needs to be able to be placed on any creature, more like [Bond Beetle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBond%20Beetle%5d), instead of [Elvish Vanguard](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElvish%20Vanguard%5d).

I'm not sure if any such creature or enchantment or artifact exists but if there is that would be spectacular.

While there are plenty of cards that have similar effects, I am looking for one almost functionally identical to [Cathars' Crusade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCathars%27%5d%2b%5bCrusade%5d). The deck has a lot of tutors in the form of transmute and [Night Dealings](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNight%20Dealings%5d) and I realized that in order to be able to do infinite with [Workhorse](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWorkhorse%5d) and [Animation Module](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAnimation%20Module%5d) I just need a way to replenish the counters. The deck also has a lot of sac outlets due to Marchesa's ability to recur the sacrificed creatures. Being able to place even one counter on any creature would be great because it could trigger other effects as well as protect the creature I just sacrificed. Again I'm not sure if this card exists but I feel like I have seen this effect before outside of green white.

Comment: Now is it a creature you're looking for, or any type of permanent?

Comment: I'm sorry I was not clear, I am looking for any type of permanent

Answer (score 2):

## [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Advanced.aspx) is quite a powerful search tool if you know how to use it.

Even a good search will probably pull up lots of useless cards, but a page or two of results is easily searchable (I recommend using Visual Spoiler mode, it makes it a lot easier to quickly scroll through, in my opinion), and some of the cards that don't do quite what you're looking for may be useful anyways.

[Here](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?output=spoiler&method=visual&action=advanced&color=+%40(%7c%5bB%5d%7c%5bR%5d%7c%5bU%5d%7c%5bC%5d)&text=+%5b%22enters+the+battlefield%22%5d+%5bcounter%5d+%5bcreature%5d+%5b+1%2f+1%5d+!%5bfabricate%5d+!%5bbloodthirst%5d+!%5bdevour%5d+!%5bevolve%5d+!%5bmodular%5d+!%5bsunburst%5d) is my search:
Colors: Red, Black, Blue or Colorless (exclude all other colors)
Text contains: "enters the battlefield", "counter", "creature", "+1/+1"
Text does not contain: fabricate, bloodthirst, devour, evolve, modular, sunburst

I chose my search terms to closely match what you were interested in, and filtered to avoid the +1/+1 counter related mechanics that were not interesting but cropped up frequently in the results.

This resulted in 89 results.  Most of them are not particularly useful, but it does pull up the Graft creatures in blue, and Sage of Fables, Oona's Blackguard, and Olivia, Mobilized for War which are all along the lines that you were looking for, albeit more limited in scope.  It also pulls up a bunch of creatures that enter the battlefield with +1/+1 counters which may be interested although not what you were looking for.

The dangers of searching this way is that you get exactly what you ask for.  This search does not, for example, pull up Mikaeus the Unhallowed, because the wording of the Undying reminder text is "When this creature dies, if it had no +1/+1 counters on it, **return it to the battlefield** under its owner's control with a +1/+1 counter on it." This text misses the "enters the battlefield" search term I was using, and therefore a new search would be needed in order to find it.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I have known how the gatherer works but it seemed to complicated for me to try to use to find a specific card. Thank you for the tips I will try it out using it with varius search terms. I already have Oona's Blackguard and I will try Olivia, Mobilized for War. Unfortunately the deck does not have enough wizards for sage of fables to be applicable. I thank you for your quick and extensive response and the instruction on the Gatherer

Answer (score 0):

The only card that readily interacts with counters that comes to mind in U,B,R is [Mikaeus the Unhallowed](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=249896). Also in general when I'm building EDH decks and I'm looking for cards that synergize well with my commander I usually check [EDHREC](https://edhrec.com) for cards to put in.

Comment: I would love to put Mikaeus in the deck but sadly he is just not in my budget for the deck. And yes I agree EDHREC has been one my favorite tools making this (my first) commander deck